# variable not getting after successfully redirect via .htaccess in php

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, variables, mod-rewrite

this is my .htaccess code

here in last line i redirect my user with a variable . it redirect successfully  for example

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://(www.)?technotch.in [NC]
RewriteRule .(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)$ - [NC,F,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-_]+)$ $1.php [QSA,NC,L]
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-_]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-_]+)/?$ $1.php?product=$2 [QSA,NC,L]

</IfModule>
```

(http://technotch.in/Online-Certification/abc)
to 
(http://technotch.in/Online-Certificate.php?product=abc)

but on my php page the variable product in not getting with the code
    $_GET['product'];

i has been check my .htaccess redirection on  (htaccess.madewithlove.be)
here it resolve it redirect url completely 
so please guide me what i do?

Comment: `[A-Za-z0-9-_]+` it may be not valid, try `[A-Za-z0-9\-\_]+` or `[\w\-]+` instead.

Comment: it Still not working after implement you code..

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see, your RewriteRule works as follows:

http://www.website.com/page is interpreted as http://www.website.com/page.php

and

http://www.website.com/xxxx/xxxx/page/item is interpreted as http://www.website.com/page.php?product=item

Is this what you are trying to achieve?

EDIT:

Apologies, I read it incorrectly, try doing a var dump on the requested page and see what vars you get.

Also, try changing [QSA, NC, L] from both to [QSA] since [L] means that it should stop processing any other rules below.

Comment: sorry dear but it work like    `(abc.com/xyz/123)`   as     `(abc.com/xyz.php?product=123)`

Comment: Apologies, I read it incorrectly, try doing a var dump on the requested page and see what vars you get.
Also, try changing [QSA, NC, L] from both to [QSA] since [L] means that it should stop processing any other rules below.